# ReviewBoard Installation errors

Tags: software-installation

When installing ReviewBoard via `sudo easy_install ReviewBoard` on a fresh Ubuntu installation, I get one error after the other. What all needs to be installed on a 'clean' Ubuntu image to install ReviewBoard without errors?

Comment: Which reviewboard you were trying to install? Are you still looking for answers? was it this https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/codebase/dev/getting-started/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had to install ReviewBoard now already a few times on a fresh Ubuntu image, I figured I put here the to install dependencies to make it easier and quicker for others (and for me in half a year from now) to install.
Following needs to be installed before ReviewBoard: `build-essential`, `libffi-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `libjpeg-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Comment: If that's the solution that worked for you, then you should mark your question as "solved".

Comment: He's right. It's really inconvenient.